# Run private docker image on minikube k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes

[image: This is the error i get after using secret]I want to run a private docker image on my minikube k8s .
But the pod is never able to pull my image from docker .

How can i pull private image in k8s and use it?

This my yaml for pod
`{apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: privaterepo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: raveena1/test
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regsecret}`

The log is:-
container "private-reg-container" in pod "privaterepo" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a secret & use it in your YAML/JSON deployment file -

**Create secret** (Like for Docker registry, you can change the registry server URL) -

`$ kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ --docker-username=$USERNM --docker-password=$PASSWD --docker-email=vivekyad4v@gmail.com`

**deployment.yaml** (use `regsecret`)-

```
---
 apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   name: local-simple-python
 spec:
   replicas: 2
   selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: local-simple-python
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: local-simple-python
     spec:
       containers:
         - name: python
           image: vivekyad4v/local-simple-python:latest
           ports:
             - containerPort: 8080
       imagePullSecrets:
         - name: regsecret
```

**Deploy -**

`$ kubectl create -f deployment.yml`

Your pods should now be able to fetch docker images on private registry.

You can find more info on -

https://github.com/vivekyad4v/kubernetes/tree/master/kubernetes-for-beginners

Official doc - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: While going through the official doc i came across FQDn. What is a Private Docker Registry FQDN?

Comment: FQDN is fully qualified domain name, for Dockerhub you can use `https://index.docker.io/v1/` where `index.docker.io` is a FQDN.

Comment: For every image FQDN remains same? Or is it just related to docker hub

Comment: Yes, if it's on Dockerhub. Are you using dockerhub or something else?
Depends on where you want to store your image or storing your images.

Comment: Then this solution will work, you need not to change FQDN, let it be `https://index.docker.io/v1/` . You can go through the tutorials where i have used dockerhub  - `https://github.com/vivekyad4v/kubernetes/tree/master/kubernetes-for-beginners`

Comment: no problem :) . Just a heads up - If you are satisfied with the answer always upvote it & mark it as correct. This helps us moving :) @aditya